# Ensure sensitive data is removed from response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have some DTOs returned by my API that have sensitive data fields like `CreatedBy`, `CreatedDate`, `LastModifiedBy` and `LastModifiedDate`. These fields should only be in the response if the user is authenticated and/or has allowed roles in their claims. My current running solution is to use my DTO mappers that have a dependency on `IUserIdentity` (custom interface).

`UserDto` record

```csharp
public record UserDto {
    public string? CreatedBy { get; init; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; init; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public string? ExternalProviderUserId { get; set; }
    public string? GivenName { get; set; }
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public string? LastModifiedBy { get; init; }
    public DateTime? LastModifiedDate { get; init; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Surname { get; set; }
}
```

`UserDtoMapper` class

```csharp
public class UserDtoMapper : IUserDtoMapper {

    private readonly IUserIdentity _userIdentity;

    public UserDtoMapper(IUserIdentity userIdentity) {
        _userIdentity = userIdentity;
    }

    public UserDto ToDto(User user) => new() {
        CreatedBy = _userIdentity.IsAuthenticated ? user.CreatedBy : null,
        CreatedDate = _userIdentity.IsAuthenticated ? user.CreatedDate : null,
        Email = user.Email,
        ExternalProviderUserId = user.ExternalProviderUserId,
        GivenName = user.GivenName,
        Id = user.Id,
        LastModifiedBy = _userIdentity.IsAuthenticated ? user.LastModifiedBy : null,
        LastModifiedDate = _userIdentity.IsAuthenticated ? user.LastModifiedDate : null,
        Name = user.Name,
        Surname = user.Surname
    };

    public List<UserDto> ToDtos(IEnumerable<User> users) {
        return users.Select(o => ToDto(o)).ToList();
    }
}
```

It work as intended but I would like to have a global and easier way to set these fields as sensitive and let the API filter them if the user is not authenticated and/or doesn't have allowed roles in their claims. After searching online for many days and  attempting trial-and-error solutions, I finally came up with my own solution and hope to have feedback on potential issues I could have. It works great so far.

My solution is to use the Filters in ASP.NET Core and Reflection (C#).

I've created this custom attribute `SensitiveDataAttribute`

```csharp
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class SensitiveDataAttribute : Attribute {

    public SensitiveDataAttribute() {
        AllowedRoles = Array.Empty<string>();
    }

    public SensitiveDataAttribute(params string[] allowedRoles)
        : this((IEnumerable<string>)allowedRoles) { }

    public SensitiveDataAttribute(IEnumerable<string> allowedRoles) {
        if (allowedRoles == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(allowedRoles));
        }

        if (!allowedRoles.Any()) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("At least one role must be specified.");
        }

        AllowedRoles = allowedRoles;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the collection of allowed roles.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<string> AllowedRoles { get; }

    public Task<bool> IsValidAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user) {
        bool isUserAuthenticated = user.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false;

        if (!isUserAuthenticated) {
            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }

        if (!AllowedRoles.Any()) {
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }

        bool found = AllowedRoles.Any(r => user.IsInRole(r));
        return Task.FromResult(found);
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        if (!AllowedRoles.Any()) {
            return $"{nameof(SensitiveDataAttribute)}:User must be authenticated";
        }

        string roles = string.Join("|", AllowedRoles);
        var stringValue = $"User must be authenticated and User.IsInRole must be true for one of the following roles:({roles})";
        return $"{nameof(SensitiveDataAttribute)}: {stringValue}";
    }
}
```

And created this action filter `SensitiveDataActionFilter`

```csharp
public class SensitiveDataActionFilter : IAsyncActionFilter {

    private readonly ILogger<SensitiveDataActionFilter> _logger;

    public SensitiveDataActionFilter(ILogger<SensitiveDataActionFilter> logger) {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext _, ActionExecutionDelegate next) {
        ActionExecutedContext executedContext = await next();

        if (executedContext.Exception != null) {
            return;
        }

        if (executedContext.Result is not OkObjectResult result) {
            return;
        }

        if (result.Value == null) {
            return;
        }

        _logger.LogDebug("Filtering action result sensitive data of type {Type} started.", result.Value.GetType());
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        if (result.Value is IEnumerable elements) {
            int index = 0;

            foreach (var element in elements) {
                await FilterResultAsync(executedContext, element, $"[{index++}].");
            }

            _logger.LogDebug("Filtering action result sensitive data of type {Type} finished in {Elapsed} ms.", result.Value.GetType(), stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            return;
        }

        await FilterResultAsync(executedContext, result.Value, null);
        _logger.LogDebug("Filtering action result sensitive data of type {Type} finished in {Elapsed} ms.", result.Value.GetType(), stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    private async Task FilterResultAsync(ActionExecutedContext context, object? source, string? propPath) {
        if (source == null) {
            return;
        }

        PropertyInfo[] properties = source.GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance
                | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(p => p.GetMethod != null
                && p.GetMethod.IsPublic
                && p.GetMethod.IsStatic == false)
            .ToArray();

        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties) {
            if (propertyInfo == null) {
                continue;
            }

            object? propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(source);
            string propertyName = propertyInfo.Name;
            string path = $"{propPath}{propertyName}";

            if (propertyValue == null) {
                _logger.LogDebug("Property {Path}: {Value}", path, propertyValue);
                continue;
            }

            SensitiveDataAttribute? sensitiveDataAttribute = propertyInfo
                .GetCustomAttribute<SensitiveDataAttribute>(true);

            if (sensitiveDataAttribute != null) {
                _logger.LogDebug("Property {Path} is sensitive: {Value}", path, propertyValue);

                bool isValid = await sensitiveDataAttribute.IsValidAsync(context.HttpContext.User);

                if (!isValid) {
                    _logger.LogDebug("Property {Path} to be cleared: {Reason}", path, sensitiveDataAttribute);
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(source, default);
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if (propertyValue is DateTime or string) {
                _logger.LogDebug("Property {Path}: {Value}", path, propertyValue);
                continue;
            }

            if (propertyValue is IEnumerable elements) {
                int index = 0;

                foreach (var element in elements) {
                    await FilterResultAsync(context, element, $"{path}.[{index++}].");
                }

                continue;
            }

            _logger.LogDebug("Property {Path}: {Value}", path, propertyValue);
            await FilterResultAsync(context, propertyValue, $"{path}.");
        }
    }
}
```

And register the filter `SensitiveDataActionFilter` like this:

```csharp
services.AddScoped<SensitiveDataActionFilter>();
services.AddControllers(options => options.Filters.AddService<SensitiveDataActionFilter>())
```

And add the attribute `SensitiveDataAttribute` to sensitive field:

```csharp
public record UserDto {
    [SensitiveData]
    public string? CreatedBy { get; init; }
    
    [SensitiveData]
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; init; }
    
    public string? Email { get; set; }

    [SensitiveData("SYS_ADMIN")]
    public string? ExternalProviderUserId { get; set; }
    
    public string? GivenName { get; set; }
    
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    
    [SensitiveData]
    public string? LastModifiedBy { get; init; }

    [SensitiveData]    
    public DateTime? LastModifiedDate { get; init; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public string? Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Circular reference is one problem I have with my code. I might need to have a max-depth setting somewhere. I had a problem with `DateTime` and `string`. `DateTime` gave me a circular reference issue and I needed to check if `propertyValue` is `DateTime` then stopped to go deeper. I needed to do the same with `string` because `string` implements `IEnumerable`.

Any feedback is appreciated. :)

Comment: if you're using either `JSON.NET` or `System.Text.Json` why not use a contract resolver to ignore properties based on your custom conditions during the serialization process. This will give the ability to remove the properties completely from the response, and keep your domain objects untouched.

Answer (score 3):

It's non-ideal for the authentication-dependent fields of `UserDto` to be nullable. From a type analysis perspective, there's nothing stopping a `UserDto` that had been produced by a fully-authenticated user from having all-null fields. I also think the reliance on reflection and attributes is too complex, and weakens the ability for static analysis to be meaningfully conducted on this code.

If your authentication-dependent DTOs have fields that, when unauthenticated, are a strict subset of fields when authenticated, then consider:

- Define a base DTO class with no attributes, no nulls allowed, and only the properties visible when unauthenticated
- Define a DTO subclass with no attributes and no nulls allowed that adds properties visible when authenticated
- For both of the above, define constructors that accept the fully-populated, internal-only object from which data are pulled.
- Define a serialiser factory method that accepts the internal user object and the authentication state, and has a return type of your parent DTO. This factory method will return an instance of the parent if unauthenticated, or an instance of the subclass if authenticated.

Such an approach will enforce strong types, no nulls, good static analysis and clear allocation of responsibility.